# How to manage the Exception thrown from some particular subclasses in Java?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, subclass

This confusion comes from when I finish my homework. I have tried to give a solution (at the end of this question) but I think it might be a bit fair-fetched. So I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

```
//Superclass
public class Vehicle {
    private int speedLimit;
    private int speed;

    ...some methods and attributes ignored here...

    public int accelerate (int amount) throws ExceedSpeedLimit, NotEnoughSpeed, TrainSpeedChange{
    //over limit
    if(speed + amount > speedLimit)
        throw new ExceedSpeedLimit("Current speed is " + speed + ". Accelerate " + amount + " will exceed the speed limit!");
    //less than 0
    if(speed + amount < 0)
        throw new NotEnoughSpeed("Current speed is " + speed + ", not enough speed to decelerate!");
    //valid value of amount
    else {
        speed += amount;
        return speed;
    }
}
```

There are two subclasses inherited from **Vehicle**, called **Car** and **AirCraft**. The method *accelerate* is not overriden by thoses two subclasses.

There is another special subclass inherited from **Vehicle**, called **Train**.

```
public class Train extends Vehicle{
    ...some methods ignored here...
    @Override
    public int accelerate(int amount) throws TrainSpeedChange{
        throw new TrainSpeedChange("Do not try to accelerate or decelerate the train!");
    }
}
```

The **Train** is not allowed to change speed, which realized by throwing an Exception when corresponding method is called.

This force the parent class's *accelerate* method to declare that it might throw the *TrainSpeedChange* exception.

Therefore, an exception catch (TrainSpeedChange) must be included in the try-catch when testing the *acceleration* method of the **Car** and **AirCraft**, but I think this is unreasonable, because the **Car** and **AirCraft** will never throw this exception, and my solution is:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    ...some methods ignored here....
    //override to narrow the range of exceptions will be thrown
    @Override
    public int accelerate(int amount) throws ExceedSpeedLimit, NotEnoughSpeed {
        try {
            //call super class method to meet potential exceptions
            super.accelerate(amount);
        } catch (ExceedSpeedLimit e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (NotEnoughSpeed e) {
            throw e;
          //never happen because this exception only occurs in Train class
        } catch (TrainSpeedChange e) {
            System.out.println("BUG! THIS MUST NEVER HAPPEN!");
        }
        return getSpeed();
    }
}
```

Although I have passed the test code, I don't know whether it is reasonable to do so, because it is a bit like solving the problem for the sake of solving the problem. Is there an easier solution?

I'm sorry my question was a little long, because I wanted to be as clear as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions, and usually you should apply or at least think about **all** of these:

### Liskov's substition principle

If the `Vehicle` class/interface declares that you can ask a vehicle to accelerate, then *all vehicles ought to support this except in extremely exotic circumstances*. This is called Liskov's substitution principle (the idea being that if you define some algorithm where as part of the input you need some sort of `Vehicle`, then LSP says I should be able to take your spec, replace `Vehicle` with some subtype of it, such as `Train`, and the algorithm still needs to make sense: You must always be able to substitute a parent type with a subtype.

As a consequence, **`Vehicle` should not have `accelerate` at all**. If not all vehicles can do it, then it's not part of `Vehicle`. You may want to introduce a new interface that captures the notion of a vehicle whose speeds *can* change, which e.g. `Car` and `Bicycle` implement, but `Train` does not. `accelerate` should be in that interface.

There is now no need for `TrainSpeedChangeException` - because the `Train` class isn't going to have an `accelerate` method *at all*.

You're falling afoul of these rules when you write an implementation of a method whose body consists solely of a single `throw` clause.

Note that the JVM/java core libs themselves don't fully follow this: It's not a law, it's a principle. For example, immutable lists still have an `add` method whose body simply `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()`

### The relationship between checked and unchecked exceptions

If it is plausible that a certain exception cannot occur unless a bug has been programmed, then **that should never be a checked exception**. The reason should be obvious - if you want to 'catch' bugs, then obviously you have to catch the runtimeexceptions (just about every -caused-by-bug- exception the JVM itself throws as runtimeexceptions, such as NullPointerException). Having to write `catch (SomeExceptionThatCannotOccurUnlessBugs)` everywhere is pointless, and what do you put in the catch block anyway? A log statement? A runtime exception that bubbles up the top results in that anyway, or if it doesn't, you have bigger problems.

The Java core libs itself do apply this rule: `UnsupportedOperationException` is a RuntimeException (meaning, you don't need to declare it in your `throws` clauses).

### exception hierarchies

Whenever you grow a cavalcade of checked exceptions, it is virtually always correct to introduce a type in the type hierarchy to cover all of it. The core libs do this too - the security (cryptography)-related APIs have a ton of checked exceptions (key is in the wrong format, that algorithm does not exist, the input doesn't fit the expected format, and so on), and they *all* `extends GeneralSecurityException` so that code that wants to react to some sort of problem with the config of the crypto but not any *particular* problem, can simply catch GSE.

IOExceptions are the same way. There's exception types to cover 'that file does not exist', 'this process does not have the required access rights to do that', 'the disk is full', 'that channel is already closed', 'the other side hung up', 'the entire network card went offline', and a hundred more such specifics, and they *all* are declared as e.g. `public class NoSuchFileException extends IOException {}` so that you can choose: If you want to specifically detect file-not-found, catch NSFEx, if you want to have a fallback handler for any I/O problem, catch the more general IOEx.

### Some closing notes

Exceptions that ever show up in a log are generally *always* a dire situation. Therefore, by convention, **do not** make exception messages all caps, and **do not** include punctuation at the end of them. *Especially* exclamation points. Don't do that.

You can catch multiple exception types in one catch:

```
try {
 ...
} catch (ExceedSpeedLimit | NotEnoughSpeed e) {
  throw e;
} ...
```

.. not that you still need this construct if you apply the rules above.

Also, exceptions by convention end in the word `Exception`. (And anything that extends `Error`  ends in `Error`. Don't let anything extend `Throwable` directly unless they do not convey the notion of errors or extraordinary exits of methods but are instead low-level control flow constructs, which you should almost never do (using throwables for control flow is usually a bad idea), but if you must - extend `Throwable` and there are no particular rules about what such types should use for names.

Comment: Your coding advices help me a lot! I think the right choice should be "The relationship between checked and unchecked exceptions". Also, I think the structure of the problem is inproper (that is directly define accelerate method in Vehicle class). But I have to follow the requirements, so...Whatever, really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to change *TrainSpeedChange* to an unchecked exception. This way the exception doesn't need to be propagated and the signature of *accelerate(int amount)* within *Vehicle* doesn't need to be changed.

This is, in my opion, the cleanest solution, because in its essence *TrainSpeedChange* exception is the equivalent to the [UnsupportedOperationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Comment: I think your solution is the clearest one, which a hundred percent satisfies the purpose of knowledge point of Exception. This should be a mistake caused by my negligence of knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce a common Exception type,

```
class AccelerationException extends Exception {}
```

and then subclass the other exceptions from that.

```
class ExceedSpeedLimit extends AccelerationException {}
class NotEnoughSpeed extends AccelerationException {}
class TrainSpeedChange extends AccelerationException {}
```

You can then declare `accelerate` to throw the super type.

```
class Vehicle {
  public int accelerate (int amount) throws AccelerationException { ...}
```

and all `accelerate()´-overrides are allowed to throw a subclass exception.

You can then catch either specific exceptions

```
public int accelerate(int amount) throws ExceedSpeedLimit, NotEnoughSpeed {
 try {
   //call super class method to meet potential exceptions
   super.accelerate(amount);
   } catch (ExceedSpeedLimit | NotEnoughSpeed e) {
     throw e;
   } catch (AccelerationException e) {
     // should not happen because the super class doesn't throw other exceptions
     System.out.println("BUG! THIS MUST NEVER HAPPEN!");
   }
   return getSpeed();
 }
```

The `catch`-clauses are evaluated in order.

In fact, if you do it this way, you don't need to catch an exception in the first place, because you know exactly what exceptions are thrown from the hierarchy.

As rzwitserloot notes, it isn't exactly great to provide a method that doesn't get implemented in subclasses; if you do this, you may be better off using `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` which is what the JDK throws in these situations (an unchecked Exception).

Comment: Yep, the unchecked Exception would be the right choice. Thank you for providing another solution! This helped me to have a deeper understanding of the use of Exception.